# No such file or directory: 'solc': 'solc'

Tags: solidity, python, solc

I have been trying to follow the following tutorial

[https://github.com/adamyala/Your_First_Decentralized_Application_Python]
     But the following error occurs:
[image]

I have followed all the steps in the tutorial. Also, I have made sure that solc is installed using npm install -g solc in the virtualenv.

Is there anybody that can help?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're installing `solc-js` but your code (via the `py-solc` library) requires `solc`. It's *possible* you can get away with renaming (or symlinking) `solcjs` to `solc`, but I think the two have different command-line interfaces.

A better solution is to actually install `solc`. See https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-solidity.html for instructions on how to do that on various platforms.

Answer (score 0):

first you are using py-solc then npm package doesnt mean anything to python. And have you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` if yes then try manually install it using: `pip install py-solc`

Comment: I have already run pip install -r requirements.txt and py-solc but it comes with the same error

Comment: are you sure your python is 3.6+ try running it again with python3 command